# small sine wave with dc bias - translate to logic time signal

Tags: signal, schmitt-trigger, biasing

I have a time varying pressure sensor output signal from which I would like to obtain the cyclic frequency.  The signal originates from a reciprocating gas compressor therefore the voltage signal is a smooth and slightly distorted sine wave, frequency varies slowly from 0-10Hz, but is generally in a steady-state.

The sensor signal is 0-10Vdc, the amplitude is around 0.5V and the dc offset can be anywhere from 0.5 to 9.5v.

I would like to translate the small sine signal into a logic level square wave signal to be received by a microprocessor board (Arduino Uno) for frequency counting.

The approach that I'm thinking of is to shift the ac signal mean to 2.5Vdc, amplify the wave and feed through a Schmitt trigger (I have SN74HC14N)comparator.

I'm sure that this is a very common situation but I haven't found a book chapter to spell it out for the electronics novice.

Answer (score 1):

A simple voltage comparator can do what you need in one step:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLTPv3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LM339 (and comparators like it) has an open-collector output, so it can drive a logic input on your MCU with the assistance of a simple pullup.

On the input side of the comparator, a simple low-pass filter produces the average of the input signal, isolating the DC bias. This is fed to the - input as a reference. Therefore, the output of the comparator switches high and low as the original signal (connected to the + input) swings above and below this average.

Note that the input signal (AC + DC) must at all times be between the supply rails of the comparator, with some margin required at the top end. See the "common-mode input voltage range" specification in [the datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2901.pdf). Adjust as needed.

If the circuit doesn't work reliably at the lowest frequencies you want to detect, try increasing the time constant of the filter — i.e., larger values for C1 and/or R1.

Comment: Dave, thank you for providing this circuit arrangement and describing the operation so clearly, I will build and experiment.

Comment: @DaveTweed     - There is a potential problem here. Tim's interest is in 10 Hz *frequency*. This comparator will almost certainly add noise to each square wave edge, which will result in a far higher frequency if the RasPi counts edges over a fixed time.